# Where are these presents in Pokémon-Amie coming from and what are they for?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Pokémon-Amie, I sometimes receive gift wrapped presents.

[image: Present received from Pokémon-Amie]

When I tap on them, they open and I'll receive a message like the following:

[image: Opened present received from Pokémon-Amie]

The names are sometimes from my friends list and sometimes just from random passersby.

Where are these gifts coming from? Are they just awarded randomly? At first I thought they were from me giving out O-Powers, but I've seen them just show up while I'm staring at the Pokémon-Amie screen. Is there a maximum amount of unwrapped presents I can have at one time? Do I have to be on this screen to receive them? They seem to contain mostly decorative items and Poké Puffs.

Comment: They usually just give useless stuff such as PokePuffs and decorative wallpapers etc.There really isn't anything USEFUL about that.At first I thought you can catch those pokemon but no Game Freak does not let you.Tsk Tsk...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're awarded by your friends (or, I believe, passers-by) pokemon (those left in Pokemon Amie). They appear to come most frequently when you sit idle at the Pokemon Amie screen, and will continue to be given if you just sit there while doing nothing at all. The item given appears to be random, but it will always either be a cosmetic item used to decorate the Pokemon Amie space or a pokepuff of varying quality. You can wait to open the presents too, at least one row full of presents will stock up and you can open them at your convenience.

You don't need to be online to gather goodies either, but you have to at least have some friends stored in the PSS, so you have to have been online and "met" some people to kickstart this feature.

Comment: Is this the *only* way I can receive more puffs? Do you know the actual maximum number of presents that can be held?

Comment: You can also get puffs by playing mini games (up to 6 depending on your performance) :)

Comment: It looks like you can *only* hold a single row of presents. I let five of them in a row fill up. A 6th will then appear, but if you don't open it or make room, it'll disappear.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have noticed is that if all three pokemon share a type, such as two talonflames and a fletchinder, you will get a special rare object. I have gotten two bird perches from this kind of match up, as well as campfire objects (from three fire types), an egg/nest object, and several others that seem to depend on the type of pokemon that appears. It seems that the more appealing/colorful exclamations from the pokemon are an indicator of a more rare object

Answer (score 0):

You can also give your friend's/passerby's Pokemon a Poke Puff and depending on the Poke Puff, you can get some really cool items and better types of Poke Puffs.

I experimented with it for a while and noted when I put a regular unfrosted Puff, I would get the same type of Puffs back and not many items.

When I placed a Supreme Puff, I get more cool items and wallpapers, and Deluxe Puffs. There is a set amount of gifts you can recieve at a time, I believe 6. If you dont open the gifts, the Pokes won't leave any more.